# Imprimir uma Lista de Objetos em Java

Tags: java, spring

Ao fazer um filtro de cursos pertencentes a um determinado turno , o correto seria fazer um *foreach* percorrendo um objeto , porém ao faze-lo ele da um erro
*';' expected* , nao entendi muito bem o porque ele deu isso e ao adicionar o *;* ao for ele da erro tambem...

```
@RequestMapping("/filtrarCursos/{idTurno}/{idTipoCurso}")
public String filtrarCursos(@PathVariable("idTurno") Long idTurno, @PathVariable("idTipoCurso") String idTipoCurso) {
    try {

        List<CursoTurno> cursoId = cursoTurnoRepository.findByTurnoId(idTurno);
        for ( c : cursoId ) {

        }

        System.err.print( "\n--- kingSizeCursos: "+cursoId.size());
        System.err.print( "\n--- idTurno: "+idTurno);
        System.err.print( "\n--- idTipoCurso: "+idTipoCurso);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mensagem = mensagemErro(e.getMessage());
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: No seu `for` você não colocou o tipo do objeto c.

Comment: Quando coloco o tipo , ele da problema devido ao CursoId retornar um objeto =x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa "tipar" o `foreach`:

```
List<CursoTurno> cursoId = cursoTurnoRepository.findByTurnoId(idTurno);
for(CursoTurno c : cursoId) {

}
```

Comment: Deu Certo , muito obrigado , nem tinha pensado nisso , navalhada de iniciante =]